# Running PowerShell as different user and credentials

Tags: powershell, wql

I am working on a project using PowerShell, and the challenge that I have now is how to run PowerShell itself.

I have access to a domain credential that has login capability on the server I am running it from, and I am planning on using WQL queries as triggers to run the script at different times.

Is there a way to do this without leaving the credential information as plaintext?  I have and use stored domain credentials within the script, but I cannot find a way to use those credentials to run the script itself.

Any idea how to do this, or creative ways to get around the issue?  I cannot use Task Scheduler for this project.

Comment: I wasn't aware of a way I could use runas with a stored credential, so I am not sure if it will work or not.

Comment: Maybe you can do `runas /user:whatever "powershell script.ps1" < mypwd.txt`?

Comment: Would there be a secure way to store the password though?  That's my real sticking point right now.

Comment: If this was UNIX, I would suggest making file read-only. How were you planning on storing the credentials in the script itself?

Comment: It's a well documented procedure to store the password in an md5 hash.  That part is done and working, now I just need to figure out how to launch it.

Comment: Wait, the password is stored as an md5 hash? As in, you pass the hash back and forth? How do you retrieve the password in the script?

Comment: Like this.  http://blogs.technet.com/b/robcost/archive/2008/05/01/powershell-tip-storing-and-using-password-credentials.aspx

Comment: Oh, well that makes more sense. It isn't an md5 hash, it's platform-dependent encryption. It's still not "securely stored", but at the very least, it's not plaintext. Why not create an  intermediary powershell script that then runs your primary script under the correct user, decrypting the encrypted password in a file and just piping into `runas` or the powershell equivalent?

Comment: OK, I'll give that a try.  Thanks for your help!